# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion

Another [Essential Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). Anyone here a graphic designer?

Comment: I'm a UX designer, so I do mostly icons and not logos. I could take a stab if others want to throw out some ideas.

Answer (score 5):

The logo should probably be simple, clean and representative of the site's purpose - similar to the seminal StackExchange sites (SO, SF, SU.)  Perhaps we could take a key tool or ingredient from brewing and have some artistically inclined folks logofy it.

As an example, carboys are used in both beer and wine brewing and are fairly recognizable.  A simple logo with a carboy, perhaps with something bubbling inside.  It would be simple and symbolic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what we were using at BrewAdvice
[image]

Comment: I like it, but we need to cover both beer & wine. Perhaps add a cork to it as well?